# Prevent clicking on view tab when editing a node

Tags: nodes

I was wondering anyone knew of a module that would warn people when clicking on the view tab if they have made changes to a node, but didn't save it. For example, I've seen a few times where people would click on the edit tab to edit the node, then when finished, click on the view tab at the top next to it. This doesn't save the page, and they loose everything they just worked on.

Any thoughts on how to warn people to click "save" first before navigating away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [content lock](http://drupal.org/project/content_lock/) module:

> Features
>
> - Concurrent editing:The user gets notified when he tries to
>     edit a node, which is edited by someone else. He cant enter the edit
>     mode.
> - By node type: Configure content_lock to lock only specific
>     nodes.
> - By format: Configure content_lock to lock only specific input
>     formats.
> - No losing content by accident: User gets notified, if he
>     wants to leave a edit form by abnormal conditions (close
>     browser/window/link click). If the user confirms to leave, the edit
>     lock gets automatically removed by an ajax call. You can disable this
>     behavior in the admin menu.
> - No forgotten locks: The user gets notified
>     when he forgets to unlock a node. He/she will be asked to click on a
>     link to unlock this node.
> - Views integration: Show all open locks using
>     any filters, as you have a views integration.